# Keep getting the following message

Tags: security, malware

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. Since reinstalling the operating system (I could not connect to the internet as my ISP kept blocking it). I get the following message

[image]

Message reads: potential malware alert.

Comment: It looks like you're running an extension that is firing the warning? Do you get the same warning when using another browser?

Comment: Retry by starting `firefox` in "safe-mode". And what do you mean with "my ISP kept blocking it"?